# Starting eclipse from Command Prompt different than double clicking

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, cmd, launch

My university wipes their public computers every time someone logs off, so I have decided to write a .bat file that copies my eclipse from a flash drive to their desktop with all my code intact. The file currently looks like this:

```
@echo off
mkdir C:\Users\lib-pac-olin-ppc\Desktop\eclipse
xcopy eclipse C:\Users\lib-pac-olin-ppc\Desktop\eclipse /S /E
C:\Users\lib-pac-olin-ppc\Desktop\eclipse\eclipse.exe
```

When I run this, eclipse starts up but behaves as if it has been launched for the first time. It does not adopt the default workspace settings and it flashes up the welcome screen. However, when I launch eclipse by directly double clicking it, it goes to my workspace and pulls up my code. It also launches a lot faster. Why is this happening?

For the person that asked, here is the .ini file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

I should note that the JVM was placed in a folder called jre within the eclipse directory, which is where eclipse looks for it by default.

Comment: Can you post your eclipse.ini file?

Comment: It is posted. Note that the -vm is not necessary in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a JVM is installed in the eclipse/jre directory, Eclipse will use it; otherwise the launcher will consult the eclipse.ini file and the system path variable. Eclipse DOES NOT consult the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

To explicitly specify a JVM of your choice, you can use the -vm command line argument:

// start Java by executing the specified java executable

eclipse -vm c:\jre\bin\javaw.exe

// start Java by loading the jvm in the eclipse process

eclipse -vm c:\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll

See the [launcher page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Launcher#Finding_a_VM.2C_Using_JNI_Invocation_or_Executing_Java) for more details on specifying a JVM.

You can manually specify the workspace location on the command line, using the -data  command-line argument.

Comment: That is not my problem. Eclipse is already set up to use a JVM within its folder.

Comment: @user284166 You can manually specify the workspace location on the command line, using the -data <workspace-path> command-line argument.

Comment: added that to the last line in the .bat, did not work

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a stab here, but the batch file is being run from USB/flash, which means the current working directory is there. Not in the newly created folder, therefore it won't know where to look for the .ini file.

Update the batch file to change the working directory in the line before launching eclipse, ie

```
@echo off
mkdir C:\Users\lib-pac-olin-ppc\Desktop\eclipse
xcopy eclipse C:\Users\lib-pac-olin-ppc\Desktop\eclipse /S /E
c:
cd C:\Users\lib-pac-olin-ppc\Desktop\eclipse\
eclipse.exe
```